# ActiveReports 10 SectionReport Byval Variable

Tags: vb.net, activereports

In the past with AR2 i'd wrote code like this

```
        Dim rpt_Test As New My_Report(_dsDati)
        rpt_Test.LoadLayout(_ReportName)
        rpt_Test.DataSource = _dv
        rpt_Test.Run()
        Me.Active_Rpt_Viewer.Document = rpt_Test.Document
```

My_Report was a rpx file and it could accept a dataset like parameter

Now with AR10 (i'm newbie) how can i pass a dataset to a sectionreport ?
I'd like to use in script the dataset for many reason and i'd like to pass it at run time.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I had used sectionreport XML  ...
I must to use sectionreport (code Based)
This was my error